# Literal type that can wrap a callable, e.g., function or member function

Tags: c++

I would like to call a function `F` with some fixed signature which itself wraps a call to a member function `Foo::*p` of some class `Foo`.  The member functions come in too flavours:

- `int* m1() {...}`, and,
- `template <typename T> void m2(T t) {...}`

and there are two versions of `F` (the second one being a template, of course) depending of what member function flavour there is.

The number of member function of `Foo` and possible calls for `F` is finite and known at compile time.  I was trying to do something along the following lines:

```cpp
struct Foo {
    void m1(int) {}
    int* m2() { return &x; }
    int x = 0;
};

using FunT = std::function<bool(int)>;

FunT Make1(void(Foo::*pf)(int)) {
    return [pf](int){return true;};
}
FunT Make2(int*(Foo::*pf)()) {
    return [pf](int){return true;};
}

static std::array a = {
  Make1(&Foo::m1),
  Make2(&Foo::m2)
};

template <int i> FunT FunToCall() {
    return a[i];
}

template <int... is> bool make_calls(Foo& foo, int arg) {
    return (FunToCall<is>()(is)&& ...);
}

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    make_calls<0,1>(foo, 5);
}
```

which compiles and runs.

Now, if `main` called `make_calls<0,1,2>(foo, 5);` the program will throw at run time—to prevent this I want to move the check to compile time by making both the array `a` and the getter `FunToCall` `constexpr`.  Starting with array, however I hit a roadblock:

```
<source>:37:29: error: the type 'const std::array<std::function<bool(int)>, 2>' of 'constexpr' variable 'a' is not literal
   37 | static constexpr std::array a = {
      |                             ^
In file included from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/array:95:12: note: 'std::array<std::function<bool(int)>, 2>' is not literal because:
   95 |     struct array
      |            ^~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.2.0/include/c++/11.2.0/array:95:12: note:   'std::array<std::function<bool(int)>, 2>' has a non-trivial destructor
```

I understand the error and I've tried each and every way to come up with something that works but couldn't figure out a way.

Is there a known idiom/pattern here that can be used here?  More generally, any ideas how to make this work (so the out-of-bounds check happens at compile time)?

As suggested by @Igor Tandetnik, a possible work-around is to use `static_assert` inside of `FunToCall` (since the `std::array` size is a compile-time constant).  Would still like to know if the array can somehow be made `constexpr`.

Comment: Related: [std::function, literal types and templates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56778142/11082165)

Answer (score 2):

```
template <int i> FunT FunToCall() {
    static_assert(i < std::tuple_size_v<decltype(a)>);
    return a[i];
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/n3YMnnf65). The size of `std::array` is a compile-time constant even if the array itself is not `constexpr`. It's part of the type.

Comment: Thanks @Igor Tandetnik, that's a good one (updated the question with this advice).  In principle though can the array holding some callable type be made `constexpr` as well?

Comment: If `a` is a global variable you can use `a.size()` instead of `std::tuple_size_v`, which I think would be better in this case.

Comment: @giik "Some callable type" - yes; you can create a literal type with overloaded `operator()`. `std::function` - probably not.